# javascript: updating Object by incrementing objectKeys value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

I am trying to make an object, where the keys are number of years and value is amount of money

```
yearlyCost = {"2016":0,"2017":0,"2018":0,"2019":0} //year(key):amount(value)
```

I have an input field in the view, that lets me make new amount and everytime  I add different addLocalCostContributor and it will check if the condition matches,the amount will be added to the year.

```
function addLocalCostContributor(localCost, year) {
        localCost.contributors.push({});

          for(var i=0; i < localCost.contributors.length;i++ ) {
            if(angular.isDefined(localCost.contributors[i].contributor) && localCost.contributors[i].contributor.name ==='Agriterra') {
              vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = localCost.contributors[i].amount;
            }
          }
    }
```

Problem is that whenever new amount is added and conditions are met, I want the year to add that amount. So if the the year "2016" gets new amount it should add the amount to key "2016" and not replace it.

If there a better way to preserve the yearly amount and update it, I am open for it.

Comment: `if (vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year]) vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] += localCost.contributors[i].amount;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `+=`:

```
vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] += localCost.contributors[i].amount;
```

Infact, just to make sure the key exists for a particular year:

```
if(vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
    vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] += localCost.contributors[i].amount;
}
else {
    vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = localCost.contributors[i].amount;
}
```

Comment: You could also do `vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = (vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] || 0) +  localCost.contributors[i].amount` and skip the hasOwnProperty check.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship your solution returns {2016: "022"} if i add 22 and if in the same year i add 1 then it logs 2 object  : {2016: "02222"} and {2016: "022221"}

Comment: Thats probably because you are getting a string in your data, whereas it should be an integer.

Comment: A javascript object can't have two properties with the same name. What you show suggests you don't have the object structure you described in your post. Instead, you may have an array of objects or something.

Comment: @TarunDugar I tried your solution but it logs {2016: "undefined222"} if I add 222 to 2016 and if I add 1 to the same key, it logs 2 objects: {2016: "undefined222222"} and {2016: "undefined2222221"}

Comment: Thats because all your values should be integers!

Comment: You are right @TarunDugar now it is incrementing, but there is something wrong in the loop that I do not understand. Suppose I add 1 euro for first time in 2016 { "2016" : 1 }, and second time when I enter the 1 euro, it increments BUT twice, so second time when I click and add amount, it logs 2 times of same object {"2016" : 2} and in other line {"2016": 3}, it seems that second time 1 euro was addded twice.

Comment: This question is solved, but I have another problem that is regarding looping. So I will mark the solution as solved because it is incrementing the amount